# Print Window Stopped Working On List Item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

we have functionality on one of our SharePoint 2010 sites that we use a print button on the Calendar item to print the pop up window:

[image: Calendar Item]

The onclick event is: `onclick="window.print();return false;"` and now only prints a blank page. This has always worked in IE11 and Chrome but as of recently only works in Chrome.

The only difference i have found is that on the printed page on Chrome the URL is the direct URL to the calendar but on IE11 the URL is the URL to the Calendar plus a random generated html file e.g.[Calendar URL]/HXMhd23.html

Can you provide any reasons why this may have stopped working? I have spoken to our ICT and they have explained that no policy settings have been changed within IE etc.

Thanks for your help.